# Broken link to StackOverflow profile in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, profile-sync

While in a chat room and you hover over my photo and click on 'user profile on stackoverflow.com' it will go to this URL (404):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/5207687/clayton

Here is my chat profile:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5207687/clayton

My chat profile also displays the wrong reputation and badges for my SO profile.

I suspect it's related to recently merging my account with a Gmail account.

If the accounts are not synchronized correctly perhaps it should simply not display the link instead of having a broken link.

Comment: Just pray they won't reset Normal's chat profile - he got no new account at all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why would we touch someone else's account in the process? o.O

Comment: @Clayton - I see the problem (and yeah, the merge is the issue), but I'm not sure on the best way to fix it within chat. I'll grab balpha for a consult once he's back next week.

Comment: @AdamLear dunno, maybe a chat reset might become global, or a dev unaware of Normal's special situation "fix" the unsynchronized chat profile.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I forget the specifics of Normal's situation (no need to describe it here), but honestly... a more robust way to fix these issues would be good. So we'll see. As always, relying on a bug for anything is likely a bad idea. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry 'bout that. Should be fixed now. Let me know if you still see problems.